# Unpacking list in Python - ValueError: not enough values to unpack

Tags: python, list, valueerror, unpack

I test my script just printing return value of .split:

```
for f in os.listdir():
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    print(f_name.split('-'))
```

and it shows me what I'd like to see - lists with 3 strings in each.

```
['Earth ', ' Our Solar System ', ' #4']
['Saturn ', ' Our Solar System ', ' #7']
['The Sun ', ' Our Solar System ', ' #1']
```

However, when I'm trying to store it in 3 different variables:

```
for f in os.listdir():
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    f_title, f_course, f_num = f_name.split(' - ')
```

it gives me an error:

```
f_title, f_course, f_num = f_name.split('-')
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

I'd appreciate any help on this! Thanks!

---

Comment: You've found a file name that _doesn't_ split into three. `print` it before trying to split it to see what that file name is. We can't help you since we don't have access to your files.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a print("f_name : {0}    - f_ext : {1} \n".format(f_ext, f_name))
That would clarify your doubt

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is the diffrence between unpacking three items and a list. What you are getting from f.split is a single item only which is a list of the 'words'

```
f_name = 'a-b-c'
f_name.split("-") -> [a,b,c] #But a list is a single entity
```

So consider :

```
[title,course,num]= f_name.split("-")
```

However this is not a very good way to do it. What happens if split returns 4 words in a list ?  Although this solves your problem, I highly doubt you should be doing it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are unwanted spaces around the hyphen `f_name.split(' - ')`. Remove them:

```
for f in os.listdir():
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    f_title, f_course, f_num = f_name.split('-')
```